# How do I write Weekly Active Users for my Admin Panel in SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

How can I find Weekly Active users in SQL Query for my Admin Panel in Laravel. Please write both Core and Laravel SQL Query.

Comment: Hi. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out this one will definitely help out.

SELECT * FROM rewardcard WHERE YEARWEEK(`time`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)

(In SQL)

$Week_query = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM rewardcard WHERE YEARWEEK(`time`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)") );

(Query for Laravel 5)

Comment: What, exactly, are you doing? What you posted as a question reads exactly like an assignment. Then, in your answer, who exactly are you addressing, when you tell people to "try out this one"? YOU asked the question!